# MSAccess - More efficient way to remove troublesome characters?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to remove/replace a few troublesome characters in an imported table.  The following is my current approach; fine for <5K record sets, but painfully slow on larger sets >20K records.

I'm guessing there are better ways to accomplish than stepping thru each record and performing a Replace:

```
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TblMatch")
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        strDesc = Replace(Nz(rs!DESC), Chr(39), Chr(39) & Chr(39))
        strDesc = Replace(Nz(rs!DESC), Chr(34), "")
        strDesc = Replace(Nz(rs!Validated_DESC), Chr(39), Chr(39) & Chr(39))
        strDesc = Replace(Nz(rs!Validated_DESC), Chr(34), "")
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
```

Would the following be more efficient?

```
    db.Execute "UPDATE TblMatch SET TblMatch.Desc = Replace([Desc],Chr(39),Chr(39) & Chr(39));"
```

Any suggestions or pointers?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain why the characters are troublesome? Maybe you can fix a bug in the code that uses this data, instead of changing the data to avoid the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing a SQL statement will almost always be quicker than iterating over and modifying the content of individual records in a Recordset using VBA.

As such, you could perform the operations of your code using the following SQL `update` statement:

```sql
update 
    tblmatch t
set 
    t.desc = replace(replace(t.desc, "'", "''"), """", ""), 
    t.validated_desc = replace(replace(t.validated_desc, "'", "''"), """", "")
where 
    t.desc like "*['""]*" or t.validated_desc like "*['""]*"
```

Though, since you are replacing a character with a duplication of itself (`'` with `''`), you will need to be careful not to run the above more than once on your dataset.

Comment: Thank you.  Very helpful.  I had not seen a criteria formed like "*['""]*" - interesting.

Comment: You're most welcome - the square brackets enclose a set of characters to be found within the string: the criteria will be validated if any one of such characters is found.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily test to find out which approach is better, though I'd guess using queries would be faster.

That said do it in Excel - it will chew though 20k rows faster than you can blink. You could import / export the sheet with a bit of VBA.

Use the REPLACE and SEARCH functions e.g. `=IF(SEARCH(CHAR(23),A1)>0, REPLACE(A1,SEARCH(CHAR(23),A1),1," "), A1)`

Comment: Yes, I could do in XLS, but this is meant to run under a button by novice users with little or no XLS skills, many times per day each.

Comment: @MarkPelletier Hence the VBA; do it in the background, the user never needs to know.